# UITableViewController subView rotation

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, rotation

I'm new to stackoverflow and to objective-C programming. I have searched for the issue described below, but I'm not able to find a working solution.

My application is a simple offline browsing app, with navigation structure.
In the appDelegate I load the RootViewController (UITableViewController) in one of the following ways:

Solution **A**

```
   [window addSubview:navigationController.view];
   [window makeKeyAndVisible];
   return YES;
```

Solution **B**

```
   RootViewController* rootviewcontroller = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil];    
   navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootviewcontroller];
```

The rootViewController simply push some views, i.e.

```
 TipAndTrickViewController *mTipAndTrick = [[TipAndTrickViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"TipAndTrickViewController" bundle:nil]; 
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:mTipAndTrick animated:YES];
```

In the deeper view I present a detail modalView (UIViewController). 
What I want is to enable autorotate only in this last view. The portait orientation is the desired for all the previoues wiews. The last view implements in the right way:

> shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation
>
> shouldAutorotate
>
> willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation
>   duration:duration
>
> willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation
>   duration:duration

Overriding

> shouldAutorotate
>
> shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation

making them returning NO/YES in the rootViewController and setting the allowed orientation in the desired way, using

> supportedInterfaceOrientations

(both in rootViewCOntroller and in the last view), I get those results:

- if I use Solution **A** all the views don't rotate.
- if I use Solution **B** all the views always rotate.

What I'm doing in the wrong way?
Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

Add these to your viewController and let me know if it works or not .

// iOS5 Rotation

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}
```

// iOS6 Rotation

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: As described in the lase part of my post I tried this implementation, but unfortunately, it doesn't work getting solution A and B respectively